# Rellenar un combobox mediante una búsqueda en Excel

Tags: vba, combobox

Tengo dos libros, en uno hay un `Form` al que le introduce un parámetro 'EMISORA' en un `textbox` y quiero que busque ese parámetro en el segundo libro (con columnas: Emisora,Serie,Fecha,Vencimiento,...) y retorne todos aquellos que cumplen en un combobox ('SERIE') en el `Form` del primer libro. La búsqueda procede después de dar clic en un botón asignado al textbox.

Por ejemplo, si busco "CETES", me liste en el combobox-SERIE todas las series donde 'Emisora'=CETES, para que luego de seleccionar una serie, me ponga en el resto de `textboxes` los valores que corresponden a la emisora y la serie en el libro 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría seria lo siguiente:

- Abrir el archivo libro2.
- Aplicarle un filtro.
- Seleccionar las celdas visibles.
- Con ese resultado agregarlo al combobox.

Te dejo un fragmento de código muy simple, ya tu debes agregar mas lineas para personalizarlo y quede optimo para lo que necesitas.

```
    vEmisor = txtEmisor.Text
    Workbooks.Open ("D:\Ejemplo\Libro2.xlsx")
    Worksheets("Hoja1").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$N$200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & vEmisor, Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

`Set vSeries = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each vSerie In vSeries
    cbxSerie.AddItem vSerie.Value
Next
Workbooks("Libro2.xlsx").Close Savechanges:=False`

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El caso es que el libro 2 no es fijo, se actualiza diario y el nombre de éste cambia. Usando `Vector = Application.GetOpenFilename` ¿Qué tanto cambiaría?

Comment: También, el rango de emisoras no es siempre el mismo, con cada actualización este rango aumenta o disminuye sin patrón específico. @SiR-HaCk

Comment: Hola @EdgardHuerta, para el caso de abrir el libro no debería cambiar en nada,  para tu variación de de rango cuando aplicas el filtro  ya obtendrás el aumento o disminución de las filas .

Comment: Sí, ya lo revisé y quedó bien. Gracias